# can't open a modal after closing the first modal using Angular ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm trying to open a modal after closing the first. But the problem is that the second seems to be opened but it's not. And I dont understand the problem. Can anyone help me please.

myController.js

```
        $scope.detailsPdt = function(pdt, size)

                {
                    $scope.cancel();
                    $scope.pdt = pdt;

                    $rootScope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                        animation : $scope.animationsEnabled,
                        templateUrl : 'partials/detailsProduct.html',
                        controller : 'ProductsController',
                        size : size,
                        scope : $scope,
                        resolve : {}
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that your first modal is still open while you are trying to open the second one

You will have to close the first one, pass on the data of the first one to the second like:

Basically the first modal can be triggered from anywhere you want (HTML, or the controller), then you have to close the first one from myController1, and in modalInstance.result.then() you need to call the second one

```
$scope.openSecondModal = function(size, data){

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'templates/mytemplate2',
    controller: 'myController2',
    size: size,
    resolve: {
        data: function(){
           return data;
        },

   });
   modalInstance.result.then(function(data2){


   });
};


$scope.openFirstModal = function(size){

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'templates/mytemplate1',
    controller: 'myController1',
    size: size,
    resolve: {

        }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function(data){
        if(data){
            //calling the second modal
            $scope.openSecondModal('lg', data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: I tried $scope.modalInstance.close(pdt) but it's not working. Please excuse me I'm still new with AngularJs And I'm not too much getting what you said. And I'm not getting the then function you're taking about

Comment: Thanks for your time But should I make the same thing if the 2 modals belong to the same controller

Comment: Yes, one modal has to close before you call another one. Otherwise because of its CSS properties you will only see a shadow and not the full modal. This is the right way to do it